# Rails - pass variable to different page on redirect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pg-search

appreciate if you can help. I added pg_search to my project and need to redirect user back if there is no search results at all. Here is my search controller.

```
/app/controllers/results_controller.rb

class ResultsController < FrontendController
  def index
    @search_results = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:query])
    if @search_results.empty?
      redirect_to :back(@search_results)
    end
  end
end
```

And here is my layout where i'm trying to catch search result:

```
/app/views/layouts/application.html.slim
...
    .search-result class="#{'visible' unless @search_results?}
      ' 0 results
...
```

and all I get is

```
/app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:165: syntax error, unexpected ')' ...isible' unless@search_results?))).to_s)); _temple_html_attri... ... ^ 
/app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:168: syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_cond, expecting ')' ...method: :get, role: 'search' do; ... ^ 
/app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:171: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')' ; end; @output_buffer.safe_concat(... ^ /app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:194: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')' 
/app/views/layouts/application.html.slim:196: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'
```

I several different approaches from Stackoverflow, but nothing helped. What am I doing wrong? Rails 4.2.5.1, Ruby 2.2.3

Comment: `"#{'visible' unless @search_results?}` probably missing `#` at the end.

Comment: And have u declared `@search_results?`. It is not the same as `@search_results`.

Comment: Don't redirect back. Instead render a view that tells the user that there is no search results. Otherwise you get an endless loop when you hit the back button.

Comment: @yzalavin wait.. isn't @var? equals @var.presented?
Anyway after adding closing bracket i get 
`results_controller.rb:9: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting keyword_end redirect_to :back(@search_results) ^`

Comment: @max seems to me you're right about that. anyway, i'm still interested why my code is not work.

Comment: [the flash](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash) handles this use-case. You'd store it with `flash[:foo] = "bar"` and read it after the redirect with `flash[:foo]`. Unlike session, it does not persist across multiple requests; only for a single redirect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't redirect back. Instead render a view that tells the user that there is no search results. Otherwise you get an endless loop when you hit the back button.

```
class ResultsController < FrontendController
  def index
    @search_results = PgSearch.multisearch(params[:query])
  end
end
```

---

```
# app/views/results/index.html
<% if @search_results.any? do %>
  <% @search_results.each do |r| %>

  <% end %>
<% else %>
  No results.
  <%= render 'some_kind_of_form' %>
<% end >
```

### Why the syntax error?

In `redirect_to :back` `:back` is a literal symbol. You can't call literals in Ruby:

```
irb(main):001:0> :foo("bar")
SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting end-of-input
:foo("bar")
```

If you want to augment the the url use `url_for(:back)` which is the same as `request.referrer`.

```
# see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/HTTP.html
uri = URI(url_for(:back))
uri.query = { foo: 'bar' }.to_query
redirect_to uri
```

If you want to get the route object you can do:

```
Rails.application.routes.recognize_path(url_for(:back), method: :get)
```